# Cannot find the graphviz package in apt on 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

I'm trying to install graphviz on 18.04 but when I try to install it it says it is unavailable, despite being listed as having been released for 18.04: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/graphviz

I ran apt-get update and it is still missing from the repos. Does anyone know where to find it, or a PPA I could add to install it from?

Comment: Graphviz recently moved from Main (16.04 and older) to Universe (18.04 and newer). See [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer myself, I didn't have the "Universe" repository enabled in Ubuntu. I just had to run the following

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

And then installing it worked with

```
sudo apt install graphviz
```

Comment: You should mark this as the answer. It was a life saver for me.

Comment: Done. Yeah I was trying to install Netbox, and sadly the Netbox guide didn't havee a tip along the lines of "Ubuntu Server doesn't have all the official Ubuntu repos enabled by default" which would have saved me the original headache too. It probably didn't because the repo it's in changed from 16.04 to 16.08

Comment: if you cannot add repo by name, see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository

Comment: bash: add-apt-repository: command not found

Comment: @Owl Whether or not this works may depend on the version of Ubuntu you're running, but you may need to run "sudo apt-get install software-properties-common" to get the add-apt-repository command added

Comment: @ChickenOverlord that fixed it, nice work!